# Shared memory on C struct not working correctly

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

I'm working on a small program that simulates a puzzle game, where I can print the state of the board, or move up, down, left, or right but am having an issue when I tried implementing it with shared memory. I have a struct in a header file that has a char *[4][4]
that is used in both the the other files

The setup is like this

```
// Instance of Board for the current state of the game.
Obj obj; // is initialized but not here for sake of space and post size

struct obj *pobj;

int main()
{
    key_t key = ftok("/afs/x/y/z", 'b');
    //Make shared memory
    size_t BLOCK_SIZE = sizeof(struct Board);
    int shmid = shmget(key, BLOCK_SIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (shmid == -1)
    {
        fail("Cannot create shared memory");
    }
    pobj = (Obj *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    if (pobj == (struct Board *) -1)
    {
        fail("Can't map shared memory segment into address space");
    }obj
    // setting pobj values to obj values
    for(int i = 0; i < OBJ_ROWS; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < OBJ_COLS; j++){
            pobj->field[i][j] = obj.field[i][j];
        }
    }

    //Loop through and print the values just put in, I get the correct values I put in

    shmdt( pobj );
    return 0;
}
```

I get the correct values I put in

but when I access via this

```
key_t key = ftok("/afs/x/y/z", 'b');
//Make shared memory
int shmid = shmget( key, BLOCK_SIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT );//this IPC_CREAT not needed
if( shmid == -1){
    fail( "Cannot create shared memory" );
}
pobj=  (OBJ *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
if(pobj == (struct Obj *) -1){
    fail( "Cannot map shared memory segment into address space" );
}
// loop through and print out values
```

I get nothing but garbage values like

```
@ @ ▒▒▒▒▒&▒E▒x▒▒U܋u܋E▒щ▒▒▒w▒▒▒▒
▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒ ▒▒&▒E▒x▒▒U܋u܋E▒щ▒▒▒w▒▒▒▒
▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒
▒E▒x▒▒U܋u܋E▒щ▒▒▒w▒▒▒▒
▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒ ▒x▒▒U܋u܋E▒щ▒▒▒w▒▒▒▒
▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒ ▒U܋u܋E▒щ▒▒▒w▒▒▒▒
▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒ ▒u܋E▒щ▒▒▒w▒▒▒▒
▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒E▒▒}▒~▒▒
```

What is causing the difference in these values?

Edit: Fixed the issue by removing the IPC_CREAT from the second file that was causing issues and changed array to int[4][4];

Comment: You're storing adddreses of one programs memory into shared memory and trying to dereference them in another program. That's obviously not going to work.

Comment: There seem to be inconsistencies between using `Board` and `struct Board`. If you make a typedef, either use it, or don't use it. I don't recommend swapping back and forth. It somehow implies that they're distinct, when they in fact are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a brand new shared memory block in both programs. You want to create memory in `reset.c`, and read it in `fifteen.c`. Remove the `IPC_CREAT` in `fifteen.c`. You can learn more [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html), where the syscall specifies:

> IPC_CREAT
>
> Create a new segment.  If this flag is not used, then
>                      shmget() will find the segment associated with key and
>                      check to see if the user has permission to access the
>                      segment.

There's also something that doesn't make much sense. String literals are arrays, i.e. pointers, and you made Board just a bunch of pointers. The only data you shared in your shared memory object were the pointers, which isn't helpful for `fifteen.c`, `fifteen.c` needs to see the actual character data. Instead, `fifteen.c` sees a bunch of pointers that point to string literals in `reset.c`. This isn't particularly useful, what should `fifteen.c` do with a bunch of random addresses? `fifteen.c` wants to see actual letters - likely null terminated arrays. You'll have to make your Board object contain a 2D array of character arrays (Of definite length, say, 16). Then, you can share the character data back and forth in your file.

Comment: I can't guarantee there aren't other issues that would cause garbage values, but that would be one of them. If it still isn't working let me know and I'll continue looking.

Comment: It's not the *only* issue, but it's a good start to fix this.